Supabase auth error "AuthApiError: Unable to process request"
Getting this error in Supabase when trying to do an auth event that involves triggering an email to send -
AuthApiError: Unable to process request
at handleError (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@supabase/auth-js/dist/module/lib/fetch.js:74:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async _handleRequest (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@supabase/auth-js/dist/module/lib/fetch.js:117:9)
at async _request (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@supabase/auth-js/dist/module/lib/fetch.js:99:18)
at async SupabaseAuthClient.resetPasswordForEmail (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@supabase/auth-js/dist/module/GoTrueClient.js:1243:20)
at async resetPassword (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./app/(auth)/actions.ts:100:23)
at async C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:418
at async rw (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:7978)
at async r6 (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:41:1256)
at async doRender (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1438:30)
at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1599:28)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1931:24)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1969:32)
at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
at async C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
at async invokeRender (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
at async handleRequest (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\better-guessr\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13) {
__isAuthError: true,
status: 500,
code: 'unexpected_failure'
}

The error only occurs if a custom SMTP server is being used. Works if the Supabase provided email is used.

In my case, using Amazon SES, After testing the SMTP server with a python script, I found another error that told me sending the email failed because the email I'm sending TO is not a verified domain. While your SES is in "sandbox mode", you can only send FROM and TO verified domains.
The solution is to get your SES account verified, and test with a verified domain in the meantime.
